# How to modify nested object useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, use-state

I hope you can help me. How can I modify the state of this nested useState?

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
name: "",
lastName: "",
age: 0,
education: {
  university: {
    nameUniversity: "",
    city: ""
  },
  profession: "",
  graduationYear: 0
},
fruit: "" });
```

I've tried every way I know but I'm already block . In the following link you can see the state that I describe.

[example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/leer-formulario-de-varios-inputs-mw3krl?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You should not use nested states like that when you need to work with immutability, in any case you add another layer of complexity since you want a unique handler to handle the flat and nested props update. I suggest you to keep the state flat, e.g. *name,lastname,age,nameuniversity,city,profession,etc...* and then build up the object structure on your need when you need to send the data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path of the nested state object using below function:

```js
const getPaths = (obj, arr = [], res = []) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value) getPaths(value, [...arr, key], res);
    else res.push([...arr, key]);
  });
  return res;
};
```

Then we can use [_.set(object, path, value)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) of lodash to set the value by path.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import lodash from "lodash";
import "./styles.css";

const getPaths = (obj, arr = [], res = []) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value) getPaths(value, [...arr, key], res);
    else res.push([...arr, key]);
  });
  return res;
};

export default function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    name: "",
    lastName: "",
    age: 0,
    education: {
      university: {
        nameUniversity: "",
        city: ""
      },
      profession: "",
      graduationYear: 0
    },
    fruit: ""
  });

  console.log("userInfo: ", userInfo);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const paths = getPaths(userInfo);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const updatePath = paths.find((p) => p.includes(name));
    const nState = lodash.set(lodash.cloneDeep(userInfo), updatePath, value);

    setUserInfo(nState);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div>User info</div>
        <input
          placeholder="name"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={userInfo.name}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="last name"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={userInfo.lastName}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="age"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="age"
          value={userInfo.age}
        />
        <div>Education</div>
        <input
          placeholder="name university"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="nameUniversity"
          value={userInfo.education.university.nameUniversity}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="city"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="city"
          value={userInfo.education.university.city}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="profession"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="profession"
          value={userInfo.education.profession}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="graduation year"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="graduationYear"
          value={userInfo.education.graduationYear}
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <select value={userInfo.fruit} onChange={handleChange} name="fruit">
          {" "}
          <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
          <option value="lime">Lime</option>
          <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
          <option value="mango">Mango</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leer-formulario-de-varios-inputs-forked-2p0mpg?file=/src/App.js:650-912)